# CakePhp error loadModel from another plugin

Tags: cakephp

Simply my code is

```
    $this->loadModel('Documents.Document');
    debug($this->Document->_checkUserGroupPermission($docPerm, $uid));
```

The error staketrace is

```
DboSource->query('_checkUserGroup...', Array, Object(AppModel))
Model->__call('_checkUserGroup...', Array)
AppModel->_checkUserGroupPermission('guest')
[internal function]: EventsController->view('1')
ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(EventsController), Array)
Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(EventsController), Object(CakeRequest))
dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
```

I think it can't find the Documents.Document model

Comment: You shouldn't really be using `loadModel`...

Comment: What do you think the optimum solution to make a centralized function to handle (users custom function)

Comment: `DboSource->query('_checkUserGroup...', Array, Object(AppModel))` - The object is an instance of `AppModel`, your plugin model isn't being loaded. There are many potential causes for that but they are all summarized by: The file corresponding to the model you're looking for doesn't exist.